# Problem with listing of radio inputs based on array

Tags: vuejs2, radio-button

In my Laravel 2.6 application I need to show listing of radio inputs based on an array:

```
customerAccountTypeValueArray::[ { "key": "I", "label": "Individual" }, { "key": "B", "label": "Business" } ]
```

I do it as:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-radio m-3"  v-for="nextCustomerAccountTypeValue, index in customerAccountTypeValueArray"
     :key="nextCustomerAccountTypeValue.key">
    <input
        :id="'customer_account_type_' + nextCustomerAccountTypeValue.key"
        type="radio"
        name="radio_account_type"
        class="custom-control-input"
        v-model="customerRow.account_type"
        :value="customerRow.account_type"
    >
    <label class="custom-control-label" :for="'customer_account_type_' + nextCustomerAccountTypeValue.key">{{ nextCustomerAccountTypeValue.label}}</label>
    ...
```

where *customerRow* is defined as:

```
    customerRow: {
        account_type: '',
        ...
```

As the result, I see my radio inputs, but selecting any of radio inputs, the *customerRow.account_type* value is not changed.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
:value="customerRow.account_type"
```

with

```
:value="nextCustomerAccountTypeValue.key"
```

and it should work.